# How do Desktop Only items get into my Mobile world?

Tags: terraria-mobile

While digging, I found a long tunnel that went straight down. I fell to the bottom, where it had a sword. I realized this was an **enchanted sword shrine.** I am pretty sure those are only on desktop, and I checked the Wikipedia. How did this end up on my Mobile World??

Comment: I'm so confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you got an Enchanted Sword from it (which is not possible), it wasn't an enchanted sword shrine, but just the generic "sword in stone" breakable object.

Comment: But I did get a sword from it And now I'm even more confused